# how to send mp3 file from flask to javascript and play on html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, mp3

When I try to add

```
<audio src="xxx.mp3"></audio>
```

on html web page,it always say:

```
can't find the source
```

,it seems that the .mp3 file can't be find on the server(port:5000)
How can I solve this problem?
I use flask framework and I am new to it,how to play local .mp3 files on the html page?
Thank you very much!
(Only css,js,image can be upload through "/static" folder?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will succeed

```html
<audio src="xxx.mp3"controls> <source src="xxx.mp3" type="audio/mp4" ></audio>
```